# Monitor Has Lines and Wrong Colours on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, x11, wayland, monitors

I've just plugged in my monitor to my Lenovo ThinkPad T14s Gen 2i with Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) running Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.3 LTS, and on both Wayland and X11, it looks completely wrong, and a portion of the right is cutoff. It works fine in Windows 11.

[image: External Monitor]
What it should look like (note clock is displayed in bottom right):
[image: What it should look like]

I've tried changing the colour profile, resolution, and refresh rate, as well as closing the lid (turning off laptop screen) to no avail.